# Android GIF rendering issues

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, gif, animated-gif

In my activity_main.xml file, I have the following block of code because I want to use this to animate my GIF file.

```
<matthewallenlinsoftware.keepy_uppy.PlayGifView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/viewGif"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.04"
    android:src="@drawable/bouncing_ball" />
```

The animation of the GIF works fine but this causes Rendering Problems in Android Studio. Is there a fix to this?

The code for PlayGifView is below:

```
public class PlayGifView extends View {

private static final int DEFAULT_MOVIEW_DURATION = 1000;

private int mMovieResourceId;
private Movie mMovie;

private long mMovieStart = 0;
private int mCurrentAnimationTime = 0;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public PlayGifView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    /**
     * Starting from HONEYCOMB have to turn off HardWare acceleration to draw
     * Movie on Canvas.
     */
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
}

public void setImageResource(int mvId){
    this.mMovieResourceId = mvId;
    mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(mMovieResourceId));
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if(mMovie != null){
        setMeasuredDimension(mMovie.width(), mMovie.height());
    }else{
        setMeasuredDimension(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), getSuggestedMinimumHeight());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mMovie != null){
        updateAnimtionTime();
        drawGif(canvas);
        invalidate();
    }else{
        drawGif(canvas);    //NULLPTR EXCEPTION
    }
}

private void updateAnimtionTime() {
    long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

    if (mMovieStart == 0) {
        mMovieStart = now;
    }
    int dur = mMovie.duration();
    if (dur == 0) {
        dur = DEFAULT_MOVIEW_DURATION;
    }
    mCurrentAnimationTime = (int) ((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
}

private void drawGif(Canvas canvas) {
    mMovie.setTime(mCurrentAnimationTime);  //NULLPTR EXCEPTION
    mMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
    canvas.restore();
}

}
```

Comment: Is the PlayGifView class yours then? The problem may be on that code, so post it.

Comment: @weston I edited it to include the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you have kept GIF in folders like hdpi, xhdpi etc.. Copy the GIF in directly 'drawable' also or try to run android studio as administrator...

Comment: can you clarify what you mean? My GIF is in the 'drawable' folder. It appears that the problem is that I have not dragged and dropped a widget onto the Layout Preview to represent my GIF, so that might be causing the issue. Would I have to put the GIF as an ImageView in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no problem using different libraries then you can try this

**[Droids on Roids](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable)**

```
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.22'
```

and top-level **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

In your view XML

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView 
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”  
    android:layout_height=”match_parent” 
    android:src=”@drawable/src_anim” 
    android:background=”@drawable/bg_anim”/>
```

If you need an online downloading feature, then you can try [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

```
repositories {
  google()
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
}
```

then load from URL

```
Glide.with(this).load(“your_gif.gif") .into(imageView);
```

and load from resource

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.your_gif).into(imageView);
```